# Import neighboring module in python

Tags: python, import

I have the following folder structure to keep my unit testing files separate from the actual module they test.

```
proj/
  foo/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
  tests/
    test.py
```

How can I import module `foo` from `test.py`?

Comment: Where does `proj` sit relative to your Python path? How are you running your tests? Are you using a test runner like `nose`?

Comment: Which "module foo"? `foo` or `foo.foo`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `proj` is not in my python path.  I am running it with `unittest` with `proj $ python tests/test.py`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams `foo`, I renamed `foo.py` to `bar.py` to avoid confusion.

Comment: @cheezsteak: then `tests` is on your path, but `foo` will not be unless you explicitly add it to your path. A test runner like nose can help manage the path for tests.

Comment: Or if you run `python -m tests.test`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: yes, provided a `__init__.py` file is added to `tests`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
from .. import foo
```